# " :checked " this property is not working

Tags: html, css

My HTML code looks like this:

```
<nav>
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li class="hvr-shutter-out-horizontal"><a href="#">Login</a></li>
            <li class="hvr-shutter-out-horizontal"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li class="hvr-shutter-out-horizontal"><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
            <li class="hvr-shutter-out-horizontal"><a href="#">Feedback</a></li>
            <li class="hvr-shutter-out-horizontal"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <label for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
```

and the css file is

```
.nav-links {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;  
}

#toggle:checked + .nav-links{
    display: block;
}
```

But the checked property here is not working. Please help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `+` selector is not correct. Please check this https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp
As your css selector, `.nav-links` have to be placed immediately after `#toggle`

Answer (score 0):

[`+` is the next-sibling combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#adjacent-sibling-combinators).

`.nav-links` is not next after the input, it is the child of the `nav` that is two siblings before it.

There is no combinator which targets a previous element.

---

Toggle menus are best achieved with JavaScript which can toggle a class on the element and add suitable `aria` states to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

`.nav-links` is not in the same sibling as `#toggle`, but `nav` is. You can either do `#toggle:checked` or `#toggle:checked + nav`.

Comment: I tried doing `#toggle:checked + nav` but id doesnt work . The whole code is inside a header tag. Then what should i do to make it work